# Problem with BooleanRegion

Tags: regions

Suppose I take the following regions

`B=Disk[{-0.932439, -0.185209}, 1.04]`, `A=RegionDifference[Disk[{0, 0}, 10], B]`

When I try to compute and display intersections of regions with `A`, Mathematica is incredibly slow and eventually I have to force quit. I'm wondering if there is some glaring problem with trying to do this. When I compute intersections with `B` I face no problem. Is there some reason why this Boolean region `A` gives problems?

For example `RegionIntersection[A, B]` gives some BooleanRegion but when I apply `Region` to this result to visualise the answer, Mathematica is stuck. It seems that Mathematica does not like that this is an empty region. Of course, here it is easy to spot but in general I won't be able to hand check if the region in empty. A concrete example is the following. Take `RegionIntersection[A, Disk[{-0.5, 0}, 0.2]]`. This gives a BooleanRegion and if you plot both of these regions one see that these are disjoint. However, `RegionIntersection[newA, Disk[{-0.5, 0}, 0.2]] === EmptyRegion[2]` returns false.

Comment: `B = Disk[{-0.932439, -0.185209}, 1.04];
A = RegionDifference[Disk[{0, 0}, 10], B];
Region[A]` Too faster in 13.0.1 version.

Comment: ```BooleanRegion[#1 && ! #2 && #3 &, {Disk[{0, 0}, 10], 
  Disk[{-0.932439`, -0.185209`}, 1.04`], 
  Disk[{-0.932439`, -0.185209`}, 1.04`]}]``` The Region command hangs up trying to plot it on v12.2.0 Win7-x64.